# How to call class static and unstatic method with call_user_func()?

Tags: php

I've custom code where I run class methods:

```
$object = new UserClass();
$method = 'create';
$params = ['name' => 'John'];

$reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($object, $method);

if($reflectionMethod->isStatic()) {
    return $object::$method($params);
} else {
    return $object->$method($params);
}
```

How I can run class method without checking if the method type is static or not, with one line if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class UserClass {
    public static function foo(string $name) {
        echo 'hi ', $name, "\n";
    }

    public function bar(string $name) {
        echo "bye ", $name, "\n";
    }
}

$object  = new UserClass();
$methods = ['foo', 'bar'];


foreach ($methods as $method) {
    call_user_func([$object, $method], "Bobby");
}
```

Outputs:

```
hi Bobby
bye Bobby
```

`call_user_func()` does not care if the method is static or not. It work in both cases.

Comment: How to pass args then @yivi ?

Comment: Or `call_user_func_array([ $object, $method ], $params );`

Comment: Any arguments after the callable are passed to the called method.